# Android Login Activity and Home Activity redirection

Tags: android, authentication, session-state

I am managing the session using shared preference in my application. If the user is logged in it must show the home activity, if not it must show login activity.

With the help of http://www.androidhive.info/2012/08/android-session-management-using-shared-preferences/

I tried to create home and redirect to login activity if the user is not logged in.

Is this right?, or is there any better solution.

Thanks,
Bennet.

Comment: If your application only stores 1 username and password, then your method is perfect, no need to change it.
But if you will have multiple users, it is adviced to use SQLite Database.

Comment: Hi Stealz, the actual login credentials are checked in remote server. not in mobile. shared preference is used to store only one user info.

Answer (score 9):

Here is what Im doing when logging the user in :

```
     private static final String APP_SHARED_PREFS = "asdasd_preferences";
     SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
     Editor editor;
     private boolean isUserLoggedIn;

    sharedPrefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(APP_SHARED_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    isUserLoggedIn = sharedPrefs.getBoolean("userLoggedInState", false);
    editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("userLoggedInState", true);
    editor.putInt("currentLoggedInUserId", userId);
    editor.commit();

    Intent signupSuccessHome = new Intent(this, Home.class);
    signupSuccessHome.putExtra("reqFrom", "login");
    startActivity(signupSuccessHome);
    finish();
```

in the base activity that all my activities extend (it contains the actionbar and the sliding menu) I have the following check:
(mainactivity is my login/register screen. if the user is not logged in im sending them there)

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    sharedPrefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(APP_SHARED_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    isUserLoggedIn = sharedPrefs.getBoolean("userLoggedInState", false);
    if (!isUserLoggedIn) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    sharedPrefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(APP_SHARED_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    isUserLoggedIn = sharedPrefs.getBoolean("userLoggedInState", false);
    if (!isUserLoggedIn) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
    super.onRestart();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    sharedPrefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences(APP_SHARED_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    isUserLoggedIn = sharedPrefs.getBoolean("userLoggedInState", false);
    currentlyLoggedInUser = sharedPrefs.getInt("currentLoggedInUserId", 0);
    currentlyLoggedInUserString = Integer.toString(currentlyLoggedInUser);
    if (!isUserLoggedIn) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
```

and to prevent the user from going back to the login screen:
in Login.java:

```
    isUserLoggedIn = sharedPrefs.getBoolean("userLoggedInState", false);
    if (isUserLoggedIn) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
```

in Home.java:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Comment: Did you set your login activity as the launcher?

Answer (score 0):

As far as my experience goes, I also use the shared preferences for Login page/Home Page redirection. The only difference is, my first page is a splash screen which I show for a certain duration of time. After that I check the logged in status with the shared preferences, and do the necessary redirection.

One point should be noted here though, some servers require you to send new login request after a certain duration (configurable value sent from the server as part of login response) has passed. So you might want to take a look at that. In another one of my apps, I need to send a login request every time the app is launched, so I just store the login values (userName/Pass) in the shared prefs after the first login, and do the login part silently (without showing the login screen) after the splash screen. So it all depends on your requirements. But in all of my apps, I have used shared prefs only.

Maybe someone else can suggest a better approach.

Comment: Thanks, That seems good idea. But, my case i like facebook login in android. absolutely same as that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this -

In the onResume() of your condition checking activity(or splash activity), you can check like this (I am writing the psuedo code only) -

```
onResume() {
   if(userIsLoggedIn) {
     val intent = Intent(this@CurrentActivity, HomeActivity::class.java)
     startActivity(intent)
     finish() // Do not forget to finish the current activity; This will help in not letting the user to come back this the CurrentActivity(condition checking activity)
   } 
    else {
      val intent = Intent(this@CurrentActivity, LogInActivity::class.java)
      startActivity(intent)
      finish()
   }
}
```